# How to delete a mask in the movie clip editor?

Tags: tracking, masking, movie-clip-editor, compositing-nodes

[image]

I can't find find a way to remove masking data in the *Movie Clip Editor*. How to get rid of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> and click on the `X` button right beside the mask dropdown.

[image]

This will unlink the 'mask data-block' from your file. To get rid of the mask's data, you can either *save* and *re-open* your blend-file or just click the *Purge All* button in the *Outliner*:

[image]

Comment: Or after clicking Shift+X open Outliner, switch it to Orphan Data and press Purge All. This will remove all unused datablocks but no reopening needed